# How to distribute a SSRS report?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

(distinction, I'm talking about distributing a report--not deploying a report to a report server)

To our product we've recently added support for it so it can dump various stats to a database (mssql server).  Since then, I've made reports (where the datasource is my own sql server).  But if I want to get these reports into the hands of customers (pointing to their own database, obviously) so they don't need to make their own (or if they don't want/can't make their own) is there a good way to do this?

I'd rather not have to give instructions on how to use the report creator and have them copy/paste what I've done nor have them open it and change the datasource.  I'm completely new to using SSRS and don't know any of its intricacies.  I know I can query the database to see what reports are available, is there a way to just add an entire report to the database via code (c# or java)?

Comment: Are you talking about a server-side report or client-side?  Meaning will your customers have a report server on their site or will the report be run from an app?

Comment: It's already a requirement that the customers have MS SQL installed, and it's my understanding that SSRS is an option to install along with it (at least it was for me).  So I was under the assumption that I could somehow give them the report to store along with other reports they may have for the data we've given them.  

I didn't consider there may be a way to embed my pre-made report into the app and somehow point it at their database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that they have SSRS installed and configured, and assuming that their DB (tables, SPs etc.) match your report - one of the way this could be done is:

1. When creating your report use a shared datasource (don't use one embedded into report)
2. Ask a customer to create shared data source in their SSRS instance *under the same name*, but pointing to their DB
3. Profit! That's it, all you have to to is to give them the RDL file, they will upload it to their SSRS. It will use shared datasource they provided to pull data from their DB

Comment: This is definitely doable.  Is there a way to create the datasource via c# so I can automate the process for customers who aren't experienced with creating reports?

Comment: I haven't done this myself with datasources (I did programmaticaly create reports) but I think, given extensive WebService API proived by SSRS, this should be definitely possible.